# x range for non-numerical data in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

When running the following script, I get an error message:

```
set terminal postscript enhanced color
set output '| ps2pdf - histogram_categorie.pdf'
set auto x
set key off
set yrange [0:20]
set style fill solid border -1
set boxwidth 5
unset border
unset ytic
set xtics nomirror
plot "categorie.dat" using 1:2 ti col with boxes
```

The error message that I get is

```
smeik:plots nvcleemp$ gnuplot categorie.gnuplot 

plot "categorie.dat" using 1:2 ti col with boxes
                                            ^
"categorie.gnuplot", line 13: x range is invalid
```

The content of the file `categorie.dat` is

```
categorie   aantal
poussin  13
pupil  9
miniem  15
cadet  15
junior  6
senior  5
veteraan  8
```

I understand that the problem is that I haven't defined an x range. How can I make him use the first column as values for the x range? Or do I need to take the row numbers as x range and let him use the first column as labels? I'm using Gnuplot 4.4.

I'm ultimately trying to get a plot that looks the same as the plot I made before this one. That one worked fine, but had numerical data on the x axis.

```
set terminal postscript enhanced color
set output '| ps2pdf - histogram_geboorte.pdf'
set auto x
set key off
set yrange [0:40]
set xrange [1935:2005]
set style fill solid border -1
set boxwidth 5
unset border
unset ytic
set xtics nomirror
plot "geboorte.dat" using 1:2 ti col with boxes,\
     "geboorte.dat" using 1:($2+2):2 with labels
```

and the content of the file `geboorte.dat` is

```
decennium aantal
1940  2
1950  1
1960  3
1970  2
1980  3
1990  29
2000  30
```

Comment: As a side note, you may want to check if you're gnuplot was built with either the `pdf` terminal or the `pdfcairo` terminals enabled.  Then you could skip the step where you pipe the data into `ps2pdf` and just write the data directly to a pdf from gnuplot

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the `boxes` style expects that the x-values are numeric.  That's an easy one, we can give it the pseudo-column 0 which is essentially the script's line number:

```
plot "categorie.dat" using (column(0)):2 ti col with boxes
```

Now you probably want the information in the first column on the plot somehow.  I'll assume you want those strings to become the x-tics:

```
plot "categorie.dat" using (column(0)):2:xtic(1) ti col with boxes
```

*careful here, this might not work with your current `boxwidth` settings.  You might want to consider `set boxwidth 1` or `plot ... with (5*column(0)):2:xtic(1) ...`.

**EDIT** -- Taking your datafiles posted above, I've tested both of the above changes to get the boxwidth correct, and both seemed to work.

Comment: Euhm, actually the datafiles are contained within the post. Those are my real datafiles and not just smaller versions. I have to gave a presentation at a new year's reception and I was using the occasion to learn some Gnuplot.

Comment: @nvcleemp -- Oh right.  Sorry.  Guess I was just lazy and didn't read very carefully/didn't pay close attention to what I was doing.  Did you try this?  Does it work?

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, and it works except for a slight detail: the boxes in the new plot are wider than the first plot and they also touch each other. Is there a way to prevent this? You can compare http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/821/histogramgeboorte.png/ with http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/593/histogramcategorie.png/

Comment: @nvcleemp -- Sure.  I'd advise just going with `set boxwidth 0.5` or something similar.

Comment: Indeed, in the end I needed `set boxwidth 2` to get the same width as in the other plot.

Comment: Ah, I had `set boxwidth 5`, because I had the same value for the other plot. The difference is probably due to scaling differences, I assume.

Comment: A small aside question: I'm new to gnuplot. Your command works perfectly. But I have data without the header row. How should I modify to include the first row as well?